# React url changes but component state the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've needed to go to "other" web-page but when i click on the my "Link", that wraps the button, the URL changes but web-page the same

In `App.js`:

```
import {Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path="/rooms" component={Rooms}/>
                    <Route exact path="/rooms/:room" component={Chat}/>
                    <Route exact component={Error}/>
                </Switch>
            </>
        );

    }
}
```

that component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

...
      <Link to="/rooms"  style = {{textDecoration: "none"}}> //That link
        <div class="btn" >  {this.props.Title == "Sing Up" ?"Register Now!" :"Lets Go!"} </div>
      </Link>
```

I expect the changing of page.enter code here

Comment: It looks correct. Are there any JavaScript errors in the console that is preventing the page from rendering?

Comment: No. It just change a URL but don't actually change the page

Comment: Yeah I follow. Can you confirm there's no errors in your console? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/open

Comment: Also, can you provide the top-level code where you are mounting the app into the page?

Comment: In my console there is no any error but in DEV-tool i had one(but i have fixed that trouble):

Comment: index.js:1452 Warning: Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?

Comment: But i have no "class", instead i have className      (i've fix that but it still doesn't work)

Comment: I also noticed that after reloadding web-page via F5 it finally loads

Answer (score 0):

Try rendering the application inside of a `BrowserRouter` component.

```js
import { Component } from "react" 
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom"

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch> etc </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

Also the button is using `class` instead of `className`.

```js
<div className="btn">
```

Comment: i wrote that i have fixed tht "class"

Comment: I don't know, I search in the internet a it should work